# Report how many tabs I have open in my web browser

Tags: shell, browser, tabs, terminal, tabbed

I'm relatively new to working in the terminal, but I wondered if there was some way to report how many tabs I have open in my web browser. Using Mac OS 10.10, I would prefer Chrome or Firefox, but I am open to other browsers if it provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AppleScript in the command line:

> osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\"" -e "set n to number
>   of windows" -e "set ttl to 0" -e "set c to 0" -e "repeat n times" -e
>   "set x to number of tabs of window c" -e "set ttl to ttl + x" -e "set
>   c to c + 1" -e "end repeat" -e "return ttl" -e "end tell"

Just tested it now, it returns 73 for me :-)